# How can I grep a certain text and display its line and the line after as well

Tags: grep

I have a file similar to:

```
abcdef
123
ghiflk
234
sfhskdhf
483
```

I would like to search for a string, and the output should include the next (and/or previous) line as well.

So for example:

```
grep "bcd" myfile

Output:
abcdef
123
```

Or show previous line:

```
grep "ifl" myfile

Output:
123
ghiflk
```

I tried for days now to find a solution online but can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The GNU and BSD `grep` utilities has the a `-A` option for lines after a match and a `-B` option for lines before a match.  Thus, you can do something like:

```
$ grep -A 1 bcd myfile
abcdef
123
```

to show the line after the match and

```
$ grep -B 1 ifl myfile
123
ghiflk
```

to show the line preceding the match. Finally, you can use `-C` to show N lines before and after the match:

```
$ grep -C 1 ifl myfile
123
ghiflk
234
```

If your version of `grep` doesn't support this feature, you could always try some other methods:

- Using POSIX `grep` and `sed` options along with shell:

  ```
  n=$(grep -n bcd foo | cut -d':' -f1); sed -n "${n},$((n + 1))p" myfile
  ```
- Using AWK

  ```
  awk '/bcd/ {print; getline; print}' myfile
  ```

And many many more.

Comment: Why did you had to use : separator with the awk ?

Comment: @Emmanuel I didn't, was a sloppy copy-paste-and-edit from another command in my shell environment.

Comment: @Emmanuel Cleaned up the awk answer, thanks!

Comment: Or switch to `ag`.

Answer (score 6):

As well as the options mentioned by Steven D, GNU grep accepts an (undocumented) arg to the -n option that specifies the number of lines to print before and after a matched line. Of course, using -n turns on line numbering, so the -A and -B options are better if you don't want line numbers.

Eg, `grep -n1 pattern` behaves like `grep -n -A1 -B1 pattern`

---

As don_crissti mentions in the comments, this **isn't** actually an undocumented arg to the `-n` option. `-NUM` (where `NUM` is an integer) is actually a synonym for the `-C NUM` option, so `-nNUM` is effectively a contraction of `-n -C NUM`.

Comment: @koljanep  My pleasure! It's a bit odd that it's not documented; at least I couldn't find any mention of it in the man or info pages for grep. I stumbled across it accidentally several years ago when I was doing stuff with grep and head and tail in the shell, and accidentally typed grep instead of head. :)

Comment: :) It's not undocumented and it's not an arg to the `-n` option. The `-num` option is documented in both the `man` and `info` pages and it's easy to figure out why it works. It has nothing to do with `-n` in fact you could as well omit the `-n` (so `grep -1`) and you would still get the context lines. What happens here is that `-n3` is actually a `-n` followed by a `-3` e.g. `grep -n -3` ... it's pretty much like `grep -Fxf` where multiple options are concatenated.

Comment: @don_crissti: Interesting! I somehow missed (or misread) those references to `-NUM` in my grep docs. :oops: